# Using git to track common changes between two separate but related code bases with out using common history on remote

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a sensible Git remote workflow strategy for common projects which are based on a code base which comes from elsewhere and comes in multiple flavours for different hardware platforms. This is not an ideal starting point but is not under my control. Many of the files are different for the different platforms but the modifications for these projects are very local and are identical in both trees. However, I'm struggling to find a way of keeping the various parts separate in the git workflow. The code bases are quite large and each common project would use a different subset of the files, i.e. each project might touch 100 files from 5000, but each project would be a different 100 files.

What I would like to set up is a "base agnostic" remote which doesn't care what code I am applying to so I can apply it equally well to each base and then susequently track the changes relative to its "home base" without the remote knowing any of the bases.

Visually I think what I want to achieve is this

```
Codebase Hardware 1 --------------------------E 
                       \                /    / \
Common Project (remote) ---- A -- B -- C----E---F---
                                        \  /
Codebase Hardware 2 ----------------------D
```

Base 1 and base 2 are related but quite divergent (and lots of files). What I need is when I do the commit at D but without polluting with the incidental differences between Base 1 and Base 2 but they don't share a common history.

I can achieve this manually with diff files by applying the relevant diff files for the common project to both trees and then treat one as my primary and doing a diff on base 2, manually apply to base 1 and then commit. I cant work out how set up a git workflow to achieve the same and I feel there should be an easier way.

So I want common project to track the differences but referenced to two (actually many) different bases depending on which tree I am working on - a sort of baseless workflow.

Base1 and Base2 used to be upgrades and so only had to develop on one at once but I'm now in the position of having to simultanously maintain all at once. However, I could see in the future retiring base1, and adding base3 and so on.

So one approach I have tried is to create a history that codebase 2 is derived from codebase 1 so they share a common start point - and while this works, this means that I have to keep expanding my repo with 5000 ish files which don't relate to the common project. Given that different hardware versions update several times a year this quickly becomes difficult to manage but at the moment seems to be the only working solution. When I then push the changes to the remote, I get everything in the remote.

If I have understood Submodules and trees, they also don't really work as I can't move the files about and segment based on project as the projects all use a different and overlapping subset of files.

Is there a simpler way possible ? Suggestions of a better way (other than don't start from here!) ?

Many thanks

Comment: Do these code bases for the different hardware platforms have distinct legal/licence separation agreements? And is it, for each project, a single 'code base', with each hardware platform needing some interfacing shim? (e.g. like Git-for-Windows has to shim the Git code to fit onto the Windows 'hardware/OS'.

Comment: Hi - i've simplified the situation a bit so its a complex hardware system driving codebase which has been in continuous development for over 20 years - the bit we can customise is common to all of the platforms but there are parts of each of the customisable files which is specific to the platform, but those parts we don't change and not neatly separateable at a file level. Legal/licence etc is common to all an not an issue. So the situation is more like it is all shim mixed up with specific functionality components - i want to ignore the "shim" and only track and work with the components.